# Runtime.getRuntime().exec not finding file in java environment

Tags: java

I started a project in Processing and then found that I needed more functionality.  I had the following function that worked fine in Processing but now in the java environment I am getting an error.

Function:

```
void camSummary() {
        System.out.format("Cam summary");
          String commandToRun = "./camSummary.sh"; 
          File workingDir = new File(main.path);
          try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun, null, workingDir);
            int i = p.waitFor();
            if (i==0) {
              BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
              while ( (returnedValues = stdInput.readLine ()) != null) {
                  System.out.format(returnedValues);
              }
            }
          }
          catch(Throwable t) {
              System.out.format("error: " + t + "\n");  
          }
        }
```

Error:

> Cannot run program "camSummary.sh" (in directory
>   "/Users/lorenzimmer/Documents/RC/CamSoft/ "): error=2, No such file or
>   directory

I've found that there have been some very slight differences from processing to java.  I'm wondering if this function just needs to be tweaked slightly to run properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Loren

Comment: Does the file `/Users/lorenzimmer/Documents/RC/CamSoft/camSummary.sh` actually exist?

Comment: @heenenee yes.  In fact I just ran the processing version and it worked like I thought it should.

Comment: @LorenZimmer, java doesn't look for the file in path denoted by the `workingDir`. It actually looks for the script in the working directory of the java application itself. It just executes the script from the `workingDir` path. So put your script relative to the working directory of the java application.

Comment: @Codebender just tried that too.  I got the same error

Comment: Hum... Mine is just a shot of fortune, because I'm not quite good at Unix, but I suspect of the period + slash at the beginning of `commandToRun`. Already tried to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runtime.exec` does not invoke a shell, so you have to explicitly invoke one (bash, sh, etc)

Try this:

Change `String commandToRun = "./camSummary.sh";`

to

`String[] commandToRun = {"bash", "-c", "/path/to/camSummary.sh"};`

or

`String[] commandToRun = {"sh", "/path/to/camSummary.sh"};`

Then change

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun, null, workingDir);`

to

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun);`

In one line: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "/path/to/script"});`